# Instantiate an interface that extends a class

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm trying to port some code which is trying to make an instance of `http.ServerResponse`. But typescript complains:

> [ts] Property 'ServerResponse' does not exist on type 'typeof "http"'.

I've checked via the console and `http.ServerResponse` is definitely a class that can be instantiated in runtime.

Within `@types/node` `http.ServerResponse` is typed as:

```
export interface ServerResponse extends stream.Writable`
```

where `stream.Writable` resolves to a *class* `internal.Writable`

So, is there a way to work around this (when an interface extends a class) or is is simply an issue with the definitely-typed typings?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
import http = require("http");
import stream = require("stream");

let response = new stream.Writable() as http.ServerResponse;
```